# how to add multiple Array in PList

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, plist

I have a `for loop` on that for loop I have to store `Multiple Array in Plist`. But my values are getting overlapped and multiple arrays are not been creating .. what I am doing is

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    plistDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [plistDict setObject:@"a" forKey:@"b"];
    [plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

This code wont create multiple Array. This will store only once but I need the multiple times array to be created. And every time it should store object and key. What should I do ?

Comment: I don't get it... I don't really see any arrays in your code. You are creating 10 Dictionaries however, and writing them to the file. And you do same operation 10 times on the same file - which doesn't make sense at all :)

Comment: yes but this will be creating only one dictionary as when for loop moves next time ...again PlistDict will print the same thing...overlap the values..but I want to create a new dictionary/ Array

Answer (score 0):

In above code every time your replace old dictionary with new one. This is the reason you have only on dictionary at end of for loop.

try this

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    plistDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [plistDict setObject:@"a" forKey:@"b"];
    [arr addObject:plistDict];
}
[arr writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
plistDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
        [plistDict setObject:array forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    }
    [plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```